# SQL Replace ASCII With Loop

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, ascii

I'm currently trying to create a stored procedure in SQL.

But I'm stuck at somenthing.
I want to retrieve data from several columns with nvarchar values, but I want to replace all the extended ASCII values (The values from ASCII 128 and higher)

I know it is possible to do it with Replace function, but is it also possible to do this with a loop or somenthing similar, otherwise I have to create replace function for the ASCII values 126 until 255.
I thought there might be an easier way to do this, anyone got any ideas?

USING: Microsoft SQL Server 2008

Comment: A minor correction: actually it's 128 which is the starting value for extended ASCII codes, not 126.

Comment: Thanks for being so observing, changed it :)

Comment: Replace with *what* please? space? empty string?

Comment: What database? "SQL" is not the name of a database.

Comment: Oracle has the [CONVERT](http://techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/convert.php) and [TRANSLATE](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/translate.php) functions. Maybe your type of database has something similar?

Comment: @bart -  "SQL" might be the name of a database but that is neither here nor there. Which RDBMS?

Comment: @martin that's what I mean, but I couldn't think of the better term ('rdbms'). I *hate* the assumption that "SQL" == MS.  :)

Comment: In this case I did mean SQL == MS, just a habit, but I mean Microsoft SQL server 2008. And I want to to be either with ' ' or when it's a öäü I would like it to replace with o, a and u.

Comment: That last comment is serious scope creep. Do you mean just those specific 3 "oau" or really any accented characters? How long are the strings going to be?

Comment: Well you're out of luck, according to [this source](http://www.sql-ref.com/), MS-SQL Server doesn't know CONVERT nor TRANSLATE...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see Cade Roux posted some general directions while I was working on real code.

Create a mapping table.  If you didn't need the accented character substitutions, you can do without such a table.  Fill it out as required, I have mapped 200,228 and 131-134 as an example.

```
select number,
 char(number) original,
 case
 when number < 128 then char(number)
 when number = 200 then 'E'
 when number = 228 or number in (131,132,133,134) then 'a'
 else ' '
 end replacement
into charmap
from master..spt_values
where type='p' and number between 0 and 255
```

Test table

```
create table tvc (id int identity, vc nvarchar(100))
insert tvc select 'abcdef'
insert tvc select 'abätest'
insert tvc select 'abÔÖÕüûýÃ¨end'
```

The replace query

```
update tvc
SET vc = (select cast
    ((select m.replacement+''
    from master..spt_values v
    inner join charmap m on m.original=substring(tvc.vc,v.number,1) collate French_BIN
    where v.type='P' and v.number between 1 and len(tvc.vc)
    order by v.number
    for xml path(''), type) as varchar(max)))
```

Notes:

- used **spt_values** once for columns up to nvarchar(2047). You can chain them together for longer columns (max)
- **collate French_BIN** is to prevent A matching any of the accented A's etc
- xml **type** and the complex wrapper to cast as varchar(max) is used to prevent spaces becoming `&#x20;`

---

Without using a charmap and without requiring special treatment of accented characters:

```
update tvc
set vc = (select cast
    ((select case when ascii(substring(tvc.vc,v.number,1)) < 128
        then substring(tvc.vc,v.number,1)
        else ' ' end
    from master..spt_values v
    where v.type='P' and v.number between 1 and len(tvc.vc)
    order by v.number
    for xml path(''), type) as varchar(max))) r(new)
```

Comment: Thanks for this, this is very helpful to work my problem out!

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recommend using a CLR function for this:

http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/clr-assembly-regex-functions-for-sql-server-by-example/

http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/04/27/SQL-2005-Regular-Expression-Replace.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use regexp :)

Just list all symbols you actually need to extract in your pattern.

Something like `[a-zA-Z0-9]*`

Comment: You mean just use Replace(Replace(Replace...?

Comment: @SterAllures - You would need to use `CLR` and `REGEX` replace for this I think. I presume that it will be possible to come up with a regular expression for "single character not in the set char code 0 -128."

Answer (score 0):

> otherwise I have to create replace function for the ASCII values 126 until 255

It's worse than that.  The nvarchar type stores its data as UCS-2 (a Unicode format), so you'd need to replace thousands of possible characters:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx

A better choice would be to whitelist characters that you want instead of blacklisting characters you don't want.  Here's a SQL script that will return all characters from a Unicode string that fall within the standard ASCII set [(modified from a Microsoft example)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182673.aspx).  It will replace other characters with a single space.  In the case of the 'ö' character, it replaces the character with 'o' (as an example).

```
 DECLARE @position int, @nstring nvarchar(9), @nch nchar, @output nvarchar(9)
 SET @position = 1
 SET @nstring = N'København'
 SET @output = ''

 WHILE @position <= LEN(@nstring)
 BEGIN
     SELECT @nch = SUBSTRING(@nstring, @position, 1)

     IF UNICODE(@nch) < 128
         SELECT @output = @output + @nch
     ELSE IF @nch = 'ö'
         SELECT @output = @output + 'o'
     ELSE
         SELECT @output = @output + ' '

     SELECT @position = @position + 1
 END

 SELECT @output
 GO
```

To deal with your latest comment (replace accented characters with their unaccented ASCII variant), you'd need to add a lot of extra conditionals:

```
 ELSE IF @nch = 'ö'
     SELECT @output = @output + 'o'
```

I don't think MSSQL has functions to do this built in.

Comment: If I would use this, can I also use it as a later filter, so I create this and this calls another SP to filter the values out. so in the nstring variable I have to use the result I got from the other SP, can I do this (Call a SP and use it as a variable to filter out the extended ASCII code)?

Comment: Yep.  There are a few ways to get values from stored procedures.  Probably the best way is to use output variables.  Have a look at the output variables section on this page: http://www.sqlteam.com/article/stored-procedures-returning-data

Comment: No you wouldn't. Since the end result desired is ASCII set (0-127), just VARCHAR it and do the VARCHAR replacement.

Comment: @Ant using `Datalength` is wrong. For nvarchar of len 6, it will attempt to substring up to 12.

Comment: @cyberwiki: True.  However, this method removes the need for the cast.

Comment: @cyberwiki again: You're right about datalength too.  That's what you get for looking at Microsoft examples.  Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a possibility to run strings through a unpivot to generate rows of characters, map with a translation table (now a per row operation) and re-pivot to recombine the rows into columns.

Jeff Modem covers using a tally table to implement this technique:

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/

cyberkiwi has implemented it almost completely for you in his answer:

[SQL Replace ASCII With Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4990964/sql-replace-ascii-with-loop/4991759#4991759)